# Categorize numeric variable into group/ bins/ breaks

Tags: r, binning, categorization, bins

I am trying to categorize a numeric variable (age) into groups defined by intervals so it will not be continuous. I have this code:

```
data$agegrp(data$age >= 40 & data$age <= 49) <- 3
data$agegrp(data$age >= 30 & data$age <= 39) <- 2
data$agegrp(data$age >= 20 & data$age <= 29) <- 1
```

the above code is not working under survival package. It's giving me:

```
invalid function in complex assignment
```

Can you point me where the error is? `data` is the dataframe I am using.

Comment: Use `[` for subsetting, not `(`.

Comment: The function you'll want to use is `cut`.

Comment: @joan can you show me how it is done using cut?

Comment: The answer depends on **What result do you want? a) just an integer (or NA) b) factor labels or indeed c) an array of dichotomized/ dummy variables?** `findInterval()` can only do the first, whereas `cut()` does both. `findInterval()` is faster (O(log(no. of bins)) although that's rarely an issue.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would use `findInterval()` here:

First, make up some sample data

```
set.seed(1)
ages <- floor(runif(20, min = 20, max = 50))
ages
# [1] 27 31 37 47 26 46 48 39 38 21 26 25 40 31 43 34 41 49 31 43
```

Use `findInterval()` to categorize your "ages" vector.

```
findInterval(ages, c(20, 30, 40))
# [1] 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3
```

Alternatively, as recommended in the comments, `cut()` is also useful here:

```
cut(ages, breaks=c(20, 30, 40, 50), right = FALSE)
cut(ages, breaks=c(20, 30, 40, 50), right = FALSE, labels = FALSE)
```

Comment: @leian, have you tried the code? It *should*. However, when asking questions here in the R tag at SO, it is best to include a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1270695) if you want more targeted help.

Comment: but what will be the variable name of the result of this findInterval()?

Comment: Whatever you want it to be! From your example, I would assume you would do something like `data$agegrp <- findInterval(data$age, c(20, 30, 40))`.

Answer (score 29):

We can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% mutate(agegroup = case_when(age >= 40  & age <= 49 ~ '3',
                                             age >= 30  & age <= 39 ~ '2',
                                             age >= 20  & age <= 29 ~ '1')) # end function
```

Compared to other approaches, `dplyr` is easier to write and interpret.

Comment: You can also use `cut` in `mutate` instead of `case_when`. Eg.

`data %>% mutate(agegroup = cut(ages, breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50), right = T, labels = F))`

Comment: @stlba  This is /such/ a good answer, many thanks.  labels=TRUE will even give reasonable labels.

Answer (score 16):

This answer provides two ways to solve the problem using the `data.table` package, which would greatly improve the speed of the process. This is crucial if one is working with large data sets.

**1s Approach**: an adaptation of the previous answer but now using `data.table` + including `labels`:

```
library(data.table)

agebreaks <- c(0,1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,500)
agelabels <- c("0-1","1-4","5-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34",
               "35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69",
               "70-74","75-79","80-84","85+")

setDT(data)[ , agegroups := cut(age, 
                                breaks = agebreaks, 
                                right = FALSE, 
                                labels = agelabels)]
```

**2nd Approach**: This is a more wordy method, but it also makes it more clear  what exactly falls within each age group:

```
setDT(data)[age <1, agegroup := "0-1"]
data[age >0 & age <5, agegroup := "1-4"]
data[age >4 & age <10, agegroup := "5-9"]
data[age >9 & age <15, agegroup := "10-14"]
data[age >14 & age <20, agegroup := "15-19"]
data[age >19 & age <25, agegroup := "20-24"]
data[age >24 & age <30, agegroup := "25-29"]
data[age >29 & age <35, agegroup := "30-34"]
data[age >34 & age <40, agegroup := "35-39"]
data[age >39 & age <45, agegroup := "40-44"]
data[age >44 & age <50, agegroup := "45-49"]
data[age >49 & age <55, agegroup := "50-54"]
data[age >54 & age <60, agegroup := "55-59"]
data[age >59 & age <65, agegroup := "60-64"]
data[age >64 & age <70, agegroup := "65-69"]
data[age >69 & age <75, agegroup := "70-74"]
data[age >74 & age <80, agegroup := "75-79"]
data[age >79 & age <85, agegroup := "80-84"]
data[age >84, agegroup := "85+"]
```

Although the two approaches should give the same result, I prefer the 1st one for two reasons. (a) It is shorter to write and (2) the age groups are ordered in the correct way, which is crucial when it comes to visualizing the data.

Comment: The second approach doesn't seem to work with R 3.2. It gives an error could not find function ":="

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you load the `data.table` library `library(data.table)` ; and that you are working with a data.table (not a data frame) `setDT(your_dataframe) # convert your DF into a data.table`

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that your ages were stored in the dataframe column labeled `age`. Your dataframe is `df`, and you want a new column `age_grouping` containing the "bucket" that your ages fall in.

In this example, suppose that your ages ranged from 0 -> 100, and you wanted to group them every 10 years. The following code would accomplish this by storing these intervals in a new `age grouping` column:

```
df$age_grouping <- cut(df$age, seq(0, 100, 10))
```