# How do I formulate an R related statement?

Tags: r

How do you write the statement "between 0 and 15" R? I am transforming a variable into a categorical variable, and the requirement for one of the categories is to recode the new categorical variable so that the old variable (eg. X) becomes new.variable <- X between 0 and 15.

**EDIT - clarification of question**

I have been given a data set and the instruction are:

Growth patterns are generated by transforming the X variable into a new categorical variable, which can be named "growth". First category is assigned to islands in the X variable that are between 15 to 50. So that is the question, but my main headache is how to write *"between 15 to 50"* in R language. This is what I have:

```
growth$mediumgrowth.islands <- growth$SasiaUrban.X[growth$SasiaUrban.X ???]
```

Comment: What does new.variable hold? A boolean value?

Comment: I think you'll find that Roland's answer below does address your problem. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979557/622391) for additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, but I believe you want `cut`:

```
x <- 0:20
cut(x,c(-Inf,3,9,18,Inf))
# [1] (-Inf,3]  (-Inf,3]  (-Inf,3]  (-Inf,3]  (3,9]     (3,9]     (3,9]     (3,9]     (3,9]     (3,9]     (9,18]    (9,18]    (9,18]    (9,18]    (9,18]    (9,18]   
# [17] (9,18]    (9,18]    (9,18]    (18, Inf] (18, Inf]
# Levels: (-Inf,3] (3,9] (9,18] (18, Inf]
```

Or possibly `findInterval`:

```
findInterval(x,c(-Inf,3,9,18,Inf))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Comment: Hmm, ok I will try and clarify.