# Categorize age in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame contain a column for `age(numeric)`. I used this code to categorize them ta into ages groups? however, the variable appears as false true `NA`

My data name `metsother`

```
agecategory <- metsother %>% 
   mutate(metsother$Age == case_when(
     metsother$Age >= 18 & metsother$Age <= 40 ~ "Category 1",
     metsother$Age >= 41 & metsother$Age <= 60 ~ "Category 2",
     metsother$Age >= 61 & metsother$Age >= 80 ~ "Category 3"))
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipe. 2) `mutate(metsother$Age == case_when(....)` should be `mutate(Age = case_when(...)`. `==` is for comparison, `=` for assignment. 3) See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979456/categorize-numeric-variable-into-group-bins-breaks for a simpler method.

Comment: `Age >= 61 & Age >= 80` is the same as `Age >= 80`. Did you misstyped `Age <= 80`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for help, I mistook used == instead of = and also a mistake in age <= 80 ...I edited them and worked many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a new column `Age_cat` to your dataframe `metsother`

```
library(dplyr)
metsother %>% 
  mutate(Age_cat = case_when(Age >= 18 & Age <= 40 ~ "Category 1",
                         Age >= 41 & Age <= 60 ~ "Category 2", 
                         Age >= 61 & Age >= 80 ~ "Category 3",
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is on the double equal after the first `metsother$Age`. You are using an comparison instead of an assigment.

```
agecategory<- metsother %>% mutate(
          metsother$Age = case_when(
                             metsother$Age >= 18 & metsother$Age <= 40 ~ "Category 1",
                             metsother$Age >= 41 & metsother$Age <= 60 ~ "Category 2", 
                             metsother$Age >= 61 & metsother$Age >= 80 ~ "Category 3"
))
```