# Create new column so that numeric values get turned into charaters

Tags: r, mutate

Am trying to categorize integer values so that if between 7499 & 5500, returns 'Moderate-Hard', etc.

Tried mutating and putting ifelse. Total distance is numeric (varies between 12,000 & 0)

```
MSoc%>%
  mutate(`Total Distance`, 'Dist' = ifelse(`Total Distance` %in% 3500:5499, "Moderate",
                                               ifelse(`Total Distance` %in% 5500:7499, "Moderate-Hard",
                                               ifelse(`Total Distance` %in% 7500:1500, "Hard","Easy"))))
```

When I return just get those numbers back and not the titles (-Inf,3.5e+03).

Want the column to be 'Dist' and have Moderate, Easy, Moderate, etc based off what "Total Distance" column provides.

Comment: Your code looks fine assuming your Total Distance column takes integer values. It's hard to diagnose what's going wrong without seeing any sample data. But you're probably better off using `cut()` for creating bins. See the R-FAQ on [Add column which contains binned values of a numeric column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5570293/903061) for a worked example.

Comment: I'd add that, in general, arguments inside `mutate()` should take the form `mutate(column1 = definition1, column2 = definition2)`, etc.  The first `\`Total Distance\`` you have without a `=` doesn't do anything. It doesn't hurt, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: The other comment I'd make is that the code you show doesn't use `<-` or `=` to assign the modified data frame to an object. It should print the correct result, but it doesn't modify the `MSoc` object. If you want to overwrite `MSoc` with your modifications, you need `MSoc <- MSoc %>% mutate(...`

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` seems more appropriate for your problem. e.g. ``MSoc %>% mutate(Dist = case_when(`Total Distance` %in% c(3500:5499) ~ "Moderate", `Total Distance` %in% c(5500:7499) ~ "Moderate-Hard", ...``

Comment: If my guesses and links aren't enough to resolve your problem, please make your question reproducible by sharing a few rows of sample data. The easiest way to share sample data is with `dput()`: `dput(MSoc[1:5, "Total Distance", drop = FALSE])` will create copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 5 rows of the Total Distance column of `MSoc`.

Comment: structure(list(`Total Distance` = c(5844.8, 4659.26, 4437.55, 
4120.52, 5577.31)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")). structure(list(Dist = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("(-Inf,3.5e+03]", 
"(3.5e+03,5.5e+03]", "(5.5e+03,7.5e+03]"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) is the reponse I get

Comment: I'm trying to create this column so when I'm making a graph and table based off information, I can sort and provide column fill etc based off these labels/number ranges

Comment: Your line in the last `ifelse` (for "hard") says `7500:1500` did you mean 15000? Because as it its counting down from 7,500 to 1,500 which would not classify any as "hard"

Comment: Since your data are numeric, not integer, you shouldn't use a `x %in% 1:10` approach because of [floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) issues- try `5485 %in% (5484 / 1)` and you will see it returns `FALSE`. Look into [`findInterval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12979557/12109788) or `cut`

Comment: I changed from interger to numeric. Is that a viable solution? Or if I'm pulling from an API will that cause long term issues? Thanks.